# Install Android Studio on CloudReady (Chrominium OS)

Tags: android-studio, installation

Yesterday, I replaced my Win7 OS with CloudReady (similar to Chrome OS which is developed by Chrominium Project). Now I want to develop Android Apps. So, how can I Install Android Studio?

Link OS which I'm running, and want to install Android Studio: https://www.neverware.com/freedownload

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the 64bit version of CloudReady, you can install it via a [flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.google.AndroidStudio).